# creating a data bunch with fastai in colab using data from google drive

Tags: python

I am trying to load a dataset in google colab from my google drive account using fast.ai.
I am using as a dataset the alien versus predator from kaggle, from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/pmigdal/alien-vs-predator-images/home)
I downloaded and loaded in my google drive. Then I run this code:

```
# Load the Drive helper and mount
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")

%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *

path='/content/drive/My Drive/FastaiData/Alien-vs-Predator'

tfms = get_transforms(do_flip=False)

#default bs=64, set image size=100 to run successfully on colab
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path,ds_tfms=tfms, size=100)
path='/content/drive/My Drive/FastaiData/Alien-vs-Predator'

tfms = get_transforms(do_flip=False)

#default bs=64, set image size=100 to run successfully on colab
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path,ds_tfms=tfms, size=100)
```

and then I got this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py:399: UserWarning: Your training set is empty. Is this is by design, pass `ignore_empty=True` to remove this warning.
  warn("Your training set is empty. Is this is by design, pass `ignore_empty=True` to remove this warning.")
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py:402: UserWarning: Your validation set is empty. Is this is by design, use `no_split()` 
                 or pass `ignore_empty=True` when labelling to remove this warning.
  or pass `ignore_empty=True` when labelling to remove this warning.""")
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-5b3f66a4d360> in <module>()
      4 
      5 #default bs=64, set image size=100 to run successfully on colab
----> 6 data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path,ds_tfms=tfms, size=100)
      7 
      8 data.show_batch(rows=3, figsize=(10,10))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/vision/data.py in from_folder(cls, path, train, valid, valid_pct, classes, **kwargs)
    118         if valid_pct is None: src = il.split_by_folder(train=train, valid=valid)
    119         else: src = il.random_split_by_pct(valid_pct)
--> 120         src = src.label_from_folder(classes=classes)
    121         return cls.create_from_ll(src, **kwargs)
    122 


and so on...
```

It seems that it found the folder I indicated as train and validation set are empty, which is not true.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

After uploading files to google drive, you should be using PyDrive.

Sample snippet.

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# PyDrive reference:
# https://gsuitedevs.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/index.html

# 2. Create & upload a file text file.
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Sample upload.txt'})
uploaded.SetContentString('Sample upload file content')
uploaded.Upload()
print('Uploaded file with ID {}'.format(uploaded.get('id')))

# 3. Load a file by ID and print its contents.
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': uploaded.get('id')})
print('Downloaded content "{}"'.format(downloaded.GetContentString()))
```

For detailed reference, please refer https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=zU5b6dlRwUQk